# Accessing data from an API instead of a Json file

Tags: json, angular

I'm trying to access data from an API endpoint instead of a Json file but I'm having issues accessing the data. The data is pulled in fine into the ng-multiselect-dropdown function I'm using for my angular project, but not when I try and use the API instead.

*I have spent a vast amount of time searching for answers on both Google and this website and have come up short which is why I'm posting here.*

The Json file I was using seems to have a different structure to that outputted by the API. Would this be the reason I can't access that data using the same queries? The API reply contains some extra code at the top and bottom. I have added a snippet of the structure from both below.

**Json File:**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jane"
  }
]
```

**API Reply:**

```
{
  "data": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "John"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Jane"
  }
]
```

If anyone has any input on whether the two Json formats are the issue or if it's something else, please do let me know. :)

**EDIT: Added app.component.html, app.component.ts and service.ts**

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-multiselect-dropdown
  name="Customers"
  [placeholder]="'Select Customer'"
  [data]="dropdownList"
  [(ngModel)]="selectedItems"
  [settings]="dropdownSettings"
  (onSelect)="onItemSelect($event)"
>
</ng-multiselect-dropdown>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
  getCustomerDropdown() {
    const tmp = [];
    this.reportS.getCustomers().subscribe( customer => {
      for (let i = 0; i < customer.length; i++) {
        tmp.push(
          {
            id: i,
            name: customer[i].data.name
          }
        );
      }
      this.dropdownList = tmp;
    });
  }
```

**service.ts**

```
getCustomers() {
    const httpOptions = this.getHttpOptions();
    return this.http.get<GetApiReply>(
      `${this.bks.getServerAddress()}customers`,
      httpOptions
    );
  }
```

Comment: For quite probably it´s the format. Different format requires different way of accesing the data. To be sure, would you like to add the components controller and template?

Comment: I have added the code there now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect your service method that makes the api call to look something like this:

```
getData(): Observable<Option[]> {
  return this.http.get('some url').pipe(pluck('data'));
}
```

Where Option looks like

```
export interface Option {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

Are you using the data property of the response?

Comment: Hi, can you read over my edit and see if that clarifies my approach? Thanks

Comment: Yeah, it's because you're not getting the data from the "data" property of the response. Try chaining the `.pipe(pluck('data'))` part of my answer to the end of your .get() call.

Comment: We really need to see what `GetApiReply` looks like though to be able to figure it out. Because either that has a nested "data" property that you need to use in the component, or it's an array of {id, name} objects. If the latter, then you need to get at it in a pipe after the http call.

Comment: Perfect, that did the job! Thank you so much! I am getting an error on one of the lines stating that "Property 'length' does not exist on type {}". taking this out causes more errors so is this just safe to ignore?

Comment: The "GetApiReply" is just a model that is part of the API requests. Here's the contents of it.

```
export class GetApiReply {
  data: any;
  message: string;
  success: boolean;
  metadata: any;
  length: number;
}
```

Comment: No errors are good to ignore! Is it when when you're calling .length on customer in the compoennt? Ah, OK. That means in the component you need to call `for (let i = 0; i < customer.data.length; i++) {`, and remove the pipe in the service.

Comment: It's an error that shows up in the editor, the "length" value has a red line under it with the previous error message. This is the full line:
for (let i = 0; i < customer.length; i++) {

Comment: So the object that comes out of the service will look a bit like { data: [ { id, name}, { id: name } ] }. You need to loop over customer.data, not just customer.